# Loading Screen with React Component

Tags: reactjs, load, lifecycle

I have a Component Pulling a large amount of data as I am stress testing it. I am pulling the data using promises in the `componentWillMount` life cycle. There is about an 8 second delay on the timeline to load this data. So I obviously need a load bar.

What is the proper way to implement this? I would like my SVG not to be within the Component, but fixed in the highest component so that the load bar appears in the middle of the screen and not in the Component.

Which Lifecycle should I use and on which component? Is there a global solution so I don't have to implement a load bar on every component that needs this solution?

Comment: Maybe have an SVG then use `componentDidMount` to hide it when loading is done?

Comment: @AndrewLi I thought of that, but I am confused on whether to put in on my highest Component, or within each Component that needs the fix. What I'm interested in is more of a global solution so it fires anytime a component is rendering.

Comment: Unless you're using Redux or some other global state management, you'll have to pass a function from your highest component through to all components that may trigger the progress bar.